# Cannot find Bitmap Class in Class Library (.NET Standard)

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing, class-library

I want to make a Class Library (.NET Standard) and I'm using System.Drawing,

but I get the error:

> CS0246 C# The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm using .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: GDI / System.Drawing (where Bitmap lives) simply isn't available in .NET Core, thus not in .NET Standard, either. Progress on porting to Core is here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20325

Comment: using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update**

As of last month (May 2018), Microsoft have a production release (previously it was preview/RC) of `System.Drawing.Common`, a NuGet package which supersedes both versions of the `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` package. This should be used going forwards.

**For those using docker**

You also need the `libgdiplus` library within your final docker image, as `System.Drawing.Common` relies on this. You can install that using the following Dockerfile command:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/lib/gdiplus.dll \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /lib64/libdl.so.2 \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /lib64/libdl.so
```

**Old answer**

For now you can use the [CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing/) nuget package.

We've been using it in production code for a few months (drawing on video screencaps) and it has been working great. It's basically a slot-in replacement for System.Drawing.

Comment: I've installed the NuGet Package but I can't access its reference.                          How come?

Comment: It turns out I don't need to add CoreCompat. Thanks!

Comment: @IIRawCodeII I just wanted to point out that I've found out in the past few days that there is a CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2 library available now if you're using a new enough version of .NET Core. Unfortunately I'm using it on AWS' Lambda so I'll have to wait :)

Answer (score 44):

I'm the author of CoreCompat.System.Drawing. If you're on .NET Core 2.0, I'd recommend you'd move to [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.0-preview1-25718-03) instead, which is the Microsoft-maintained implementation of System.Drawing for .NET Core.

If you're on Linux or macOS, make sure to install libgdiplus. On macOS, run `brew install mono-libgdiplus`; on Linux your package manager should provide you with a libgdiplus package.

Comment: I think `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` is still useful if one wants to deploy a pure .NET Standard dependent library. A question: could the dependency of `CoreCompat.System.Drawing` be lowered to just .NET Standard 1.2? This allow it to be compatible also with .NET Framework 4.5