# C# capturing screen in console application

Tags: c#, console-application, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot in a console application (not windows forms), then I want to take that screenshot and send it to my friend through socket, but so far I don't have any issues with socket.

All tutorials I can find use windows forms and use:

`using System.Drawing.Imaging;`

But if I try to do that, it gives me an error saying:

> "The type or namespace name 'Imaging' does not exist in the namespace
> 'System.Drawing'"

Can you help me?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722409/cannot-find-bitmap-class-in-class-library-net-standard) may explain the error message. I cannot promise it will solve all of your problems.

Comment: .NET Core or Framework? What version? You'll need to add a reference / install a NuGet package. If on Framework, it's a reference to `System.Drawing`; if on Core, it's a NuGet package, `System.Drawing.Common`

Answer (score 0):

Like CoolBots said in the comments, `System.Drawing` isn't included in Console Applications. If you're using Visual Studio, right click on your project and select 'Manage NuGet Packages'. The click 'Browse' and search for `System.Drawing`. A package called `System.Drawing.Common` should pop-up. Download that and your problem should be solved.