# Using classes in Class library project

Tags: c#, class

I created a .NET Standard Class Library project, but when I tried using the System.Drawing class, everything behaved as if it wasn't there. I can't use anything in the class.
Why is that happening and how can it be fixed?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Blueberry
{
    public class GameObject
    {
        public void Sprite()
        {
            Image img; //Error: Type Image not found
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add the reference?

Comment: For .netstandard (and .net core), use System.Drawing.Common :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722409/cannot-find-bitmap-class-in-class-library-net-standard/46722736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is a Windows only component and as such requires .NET Framework (or a compatibility pack).

If you want to use .NET Standard, you can add the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) Nuget Package to your project.